# How to get title data from image EXIF with PHP

Tags: php, exif

I have many images which have both the `title` attribute and the `description`.

I'm able to get the description easily, but the title doesn't seem to be available in the EXIF data.

Is there a different place where I can access the title from?

I am accessing the `description` with the following:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($files['tmp_name'][$i]);
$description = $exif['ImageDescription'];
```

Comment: can you post output of `print_r($exif);`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this list of EXIF attributes](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html), there's no universal attribute for an image "title." Windows uses `XPTitle` which may be what you're looking for. Otherwise it could be stored in a custom attribute by the software that titled the image.